# Why this click function not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, onclicklistener

Code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    deptsSelected = '<div id = "selected">  ' + $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + '</div>';
    $("#tabs").append(deptsSelected);
});

$("#selected").on("click", function() {
    $("#tabs").slideUp();
});
```

When I click on #selected div nothing happend,  I have checked if Jquery loading and every thing seems fine I am wondering why click function does not work.
I will apreciate your help
Thanks!

Comment: no there is no errors in console

Comment: Event Delegation `$('#tabs').on("click", "#selected", function() {
      $('#tabs').slideUp();
});`